# How to disable the Scientific Float notation in android application

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-widget, android-ndk

I am executing the basic calculator example.

While dividing two numbers I am getting the result in scientific floating notation.

When I divide `3/2` I am getting result  `1.4E24`, but I need normal value as `1.5`.
I am using NDK.
The Function use is below

```
 float res2 = nativeLib.divide(v1, v2);
 s= ""+res2;
 System.out.println(res2);
 result.setText(s); >
```

The Function call is in NativeLib Class File
       public native Float divide(int x, int y);

And the Function implementation is is C lang

```
JNIEXPORT jfloat JNICALL Java_com_example_Ndkdemo_NativeLib_divide
(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj, jint value1, jint value2)
{    float d= (value1 / value2) ;
return (d);}
```

Comment: @JOXTraex Thanks for reply..i did modification in Java class files only after creating .so file ,

Comment: uh, why are you doing division in the jni? seems.. kind of not necessary.

Comment: Just for testing ,in future i will work with media framework.so i am going to NDK

Answer (score 0):

You may want to cast the value1/value2 to a float, not just assign it to a float.

Comment: I tried that also, i think there is no problem with C code its giving float value , there is problem with Java code  isn't?

Comment: i tried this sir , float d =(float)(v1/v2)   is there any possibility to convert the scientific float to normal value

Comment: I dont see how you're getting such a huge number from your calculation. Print what v1 and v2 are.

Comment: i am getting what i entered in EditText box, and the return value is the scientific float value i printed that also in Logcat .

Comment: can you post how you get it from the EditText. Show the process of (get edit text) -> convert to type -> pass to method --> return value.

Comment: Hi , sir i got the result, i changed the casting  float d= v1/(float)v2.                                                                   Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your C code is mildly broken. You're taking two ints and doing `float = int / int`. The problem here is that the casting rules are such that C will first divide one int by the other and then cast to float. So passing 3, 2 will result in 3/2 == 1, not 1.5.

You want something more like

```
float d = (float) value1 / value2;
```

Re the 1.4e24 you're getting back. That's the return value getting corrupted.

This is because you're declaring the divide function as `Float` instead of `float`. These are NOT the same thing. The `Float` is a boxed value, and is most definitely not the same type as `jfloat` on the C side.

If you change the native declaration to

```
public native float divide(int x, int y);
```

it should all start working correctly. (note the lack of capital letter on 'float'!)